# Apps Script randomly "forgets" authorization and needs re-authorizing

Tags: google-apps-script

So I have an onFormSubmit that just errors occasionally saying that it needs authorization. I am collaborating on this script with other people who may have edited the script, but this isn't always the case...

(And it doesn't help that people can't see other people's Triggers, but hey...)

The problem with this is that it is intermittent and happens on a number of projects. Also, when a script suddenly, for no reason decides it needs re-authorizing is that the error is silent... it just stops working.

My script uses a library (one of mine ) that hasn't changed either.

This has been happening, at random, for a long time now, with a number of projects. And to fix it all I need to do is run the onFormSubmit function and re-authorize.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a timeBased Add-on trigger that runs every hour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28154941/how-do-i-create-a-timebased-add-on-trigger-that-runs-every-hour)

Answer (score 1):

You have control, at least for checking the Auth status in order to no longer fail silently, using the `ScriptApp` app.

For example:
`Logger.log(ScriptApp.getAuthorizationInfo(ScriptApp.AuthMode.NONE).getAuthorizationStatus())`

Full details [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app).